# How to use dynamic VAR to create dynamic function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hubspot

Apologies if this is duplicated in any way, I've seen some similar questions on here but am struggling to apply any solutions to my problem here. Full disclosure, I'm a marketer rather than a developer and I generally wing it pretty majorly when it comes to any kind of coding

I'm using Hubspot to build a page that contains a table of data generated from a for loop. For each table row, I'm looking to include a button that a user can click to trigger a webhook that will update some of the data in that row.

`<a onclick="postDataToWebhook()"...`

I am trying to work out how I can name the function - and the onclick event - dynamically, using an ID from the row of data perhaps. I am using that ID `{{row.id}}` to make the VARs dynamic for each row, but I despite fiddling for hours I can't work out a way of creating a unique function that can be called at any time by clicking the corresponding event-calling button.

Here's the function:

```
function postDataToWebhook(){
  //get the values needed from the passed in json object
  var llid{{row.id}}="{{row.name}}";
  var accid{{row.id}}="{{row.account_id}}";
  //url to your webhook
  var webHookUrl="xxx";
  
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var myJSONStr = payload={
      "text": "Instructed landlord",
      "attachments":[
        {
          "landlord_association_id": llid{{row.id}},
          "account_id": accid{{row.id}},
        }
    ]

  };

  
//register method called after data has been sent method is executed
  oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  oReq.open("POST", webHookUrl,true);
  oReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  oReq.send(JSON.stringify(myJSONStr));
}
```

I'd be really grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass row data as an argument. You don't need to create unique variables in the function because it has its own scope.

```
<a onclick="postDataToWebhook(row)">
```

```
function postDataToWebhook(row){
  let { name, account_id } = row;
  let webHookUrl="xxx";
  let oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let myJSONStr = {
      "text": "Instructed landlord",
      "attachments":[
        {
          "landlord_association_id": name,
          account_id,
        }
    ]

  };

  
//register method called after data has been sent method is executed
  oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
  oReq.open("POST", webHookUrl,true);
  oReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  oReq.send(JSON.stringify(myJSONStr));
}
```

I modified only variable parts and didn't check the other parts of your function.